# event is not giving me the result

Tags: javascript

My homework assignment is to make an event like a party and then give prices for four different age groups.
The user is suppose to input their age and it will tell them the price they pay.
I'm also suppose to tell the user if the put a wrong number like 0 or 1000 or a word but I haven't quite figured out how to do that since I was never taught how.

```
<form id="age">
  <p>
    <input type= "text" value= "Enter age" id= "text1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black" type="button" onclick= "message1" id= "button">
      Amount Due
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

```
var age

function message1 ()
  {
  if (age >= 0 && age => 12)
    {
    window.alert("You are not eligible to go to this event")
    }
  if ( age => 13 && age => 18)
    {
    window.alert("Your amount due is $5.00")
    }
  if (age => 19 && age => 24)
    {
    window.alert("Your amount due is $7.00")
    }
  if (age => 25 && age => 54)
    {
    window.alert("Your amount due is $9.00")
    } 
  if (age => 55 && age => 99)
    {
    window.alert("Your amount due is $11.00")
  } }
```

Comment: age => xx is wrong, use age <= xx or age >= xx, equal sign is allway after

Comment: I just did that but it doesn't give anything

Comment: you are using `input type= "text"` so the anser is **text**, not number. maybe use parseInt should be better, except if the text is `blah blah blah`

Comment: `var age = parseInt( document.getElementById('text1').value )`

Comment: out of politeness to those who take the time to answer you, you are supposed to make a feedback if the answer is not appropriate, or to validate it

Answer (score 0):

quick answer for inspiration:

```js
const formAge = document.getElementById('form-Age')

formAge.onsubmit = function(evt)
{
  evt.preventDefault()
  alert( message1(formAge.age.valueAsNumber))
}

function message1(age)
{
  if (age < 13)  return "You are not eligible to go to this event"
  if (age < 19)  return "Your amount due is $5.00"
  if (age < 25)  return "Your amount due is $7.00"
  if (age < 55)  return "Your amount due is $9.00"
  return "Your amount due is $11.00"
}
```

```html
<form id="form-Age">
  <p>Enter age : <input type="number" name="age" min="0" max="99" value="0"></p>
  <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit">Amount Due</button></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name needs brackets.

```
<form id= "age">

    <p><input type= "number" min="1" max="150" value= "Enter age" id= "text1"></p>

 <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" type="button" onclick= "message1()" id= "button">Amount Due</button></p>

    </form>
```

Just fetch the value using jQuery selector based on id.
Use <= less than equal to.
And use alert instead of using window.alert.
Use semicolons after each statement.

If you want to get started on web development a good resource is Click [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org)!

```
<script>
function message1 () {

var age = $("#text1").val();

if (age >= 0 && age <= 12) {

alert("You are not eligible to go to this event");

} if ( age >= 13 && age <= 18) {

alert("Your amount due is $5.00");

} if (age >= 19 && age <= 24) {

alert("Your amount due is $7.00");

} if (age >= 25 && age <= 54) {

alert("Your amount due is $9.00");

} if (age >= 55 && age <= 99) {

alert("Your amount due is $11.00");

}

}
</script>
```